# Magento 2 enter price inc tax doesn't work

Tags: magento2, tax

Under Stores>Configuration>Sales>Tax : I set Catalog Price to Including Tax.
But when I enter 18.50€ as price for a (new) product It still adds 21% Tax (i configured a 21% tax rule)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your shipping origin settings. Locating:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Settings -> Origin.**

If not configured then configure this and clear cache.